# What is bzz protocol?

Tags: go-ethereum, swarm, bzz

While studying about swarm, I came to know that every Swarm node exposes a local HTTP proxy that implements the BZZ URL schemes. What is BZZ protocol here?

Comment: I'm confused by this term also. It's really weird that they chose this abbreviation

Answer (score 3):

The BZZ protocol is just the shorthand name for the [Swarm](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) protocol. I'm unsure why they chose that abbreviation, perhaps it's a reference to a swarm of bees that buzz?